# Mark.js highlight text wrapped in html tag

Tags: mark.js

I am trying to highlight a phrase using Mark.js but part of the phrase is wrapped in an html tag.  So Mark.js will not highlight the phrase.  I am not sure how to resolve this.  Any help will be appreciated.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="mark.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));

instance.mark("My", {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false,
    className: "green"
});

//Does not work
instance.mark("paragraph~2", {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false,
    className: "green"
});
</script>
```

```css
<style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
.green {
  background: green;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph<sup>~2</sup></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I needed to set acrossElements to true.

instance.mark("paragraph~2", {
    accuracy: "exactly",
    separateWordSearch: false,
    acrossElements: true,
    className: "green"
});